# Passing the string value of a variable

Tags: expansion, exsheets

The MWE bellow uses `exsheets` package to print the solutions to questions at the end of a book. The code doesn't work as it should as it seems to be an expansion issue. 
When, instead of `\SetQuestionProperties{section-title= \secName }`, I put what \secName variable it's supposed to hold at that point, `One` in the 1st section and `Two` in the 2nd, then all is well (i.e. replace "\secName" with "One" for the 1st couple of occurrences and with "Two" for the next couple).
Does anyone know how to make this code work, to properly pass the string values of the \secName variable to \SetQuestionProperties?

The current result is "Section Answers 1). foo 2). bar Section Answers 1). baz 2). foobar" and it should be `Section One 1). foo 2). bar Section Two 1). baz 2). foobar`.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{exsheets}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\SetupExSheets{counter-within=section}
\DeclareQuestionProperty{section-title}
\SetupExSheets{counter-within=section ,
         headings=inline-nr ,
         counter-format=qu).}
\SetupExSheets{section-hook = \noindent\bfseries
          Section \GetQuestionProperty{section-title}{\CurrentQuestionID}
          \space}

\newcommand{\secName}{}
\newcommand{\lsection}[1]
           {
           \renewcommand{\secName}{#1}
           \section{#1}
           }



\begin{document}


\lsection{One}

\begin{question}
 \SetQuestionProperties{section-title= \secName } 
  say foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  foo
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  \SetQuestionProperties{section-title= \secName }
  say bar
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  bar
\end{solution}

\lsection{Two}

\begin{question}
  \SetQuestionProperties{section-title= \secName }
  say baz
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  baz
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
\SetQuestionProperties{section-title= \secName }
  say foobar
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  foobar
\end{solution}

\lsection{Answers}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed in `\SetQuestionProperties{ section-title = \secName }` the macro `\secName` needs to be expanded once. Otherwise the question property *section-title* is set to the token `\secName` it is only expanded when used in `\printsolutions` where its current definition is `Answers` (which is what you're seeing in your example).

A usual way to expand a token before is using `\expandafter`. This is usable here but tedious: we'd need to step over 16 tokens:

```
\expandafter\SetQuestionProperties\expandafter{\expandafter
  s\expandafter e\expandafter c\expandafter t\expandafter
  i\expandafter o\expandafter n\expandafter-\expandafter
  t\expandafter i\expandafter t\expandafter l\expandafter
  e\expandafter=\secName
}
```

So a better choice is another usual solution: defining a temporary macro (`\x`) using `\edef` which exhaustively expands the replacement text. In order to only expand `\secName` once we can use `\unexpanded\expandafter{\secName}`:

```
\begingroup
\edef\x{\endgroup
  \SetQuestionProperties{
    section-title = \unexpanded\expandafter{\secName}
  }}\x
```

(`\SetQuestionProperties` is not expandable so it needs not be worried about.) However, `exsheets` is written in expl3 and already has a version of `\SetQuestionProperties` that expands its argument: `\exsheets_set_question_properties:x`. We just need to make it usable outside expl3 syntax:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \SetQuestionPropertiesX {m}
  { \exsheets_set_question_properties:x {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

In the following example I also use `pre-body-hook` so I don't to change the line in the beginning of every `question`.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{exsheets}
% \setlength{\parindent}{0pt} please don't use this but rather KOMA-Script's
% `parskip' option

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \SetQuestionPropertiesX {m}
  { \exsheets_set_question_properties:x {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareQuestionProperty{section-title}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = section ,
  headings       = inline-nr ,
  counter-format = qu). ,
  section-hook   =
    \noindent\bfseries Section
    \GetQuestionProperty{section-title}{\CurrentQuestionID}\space ,
  question/pre-body-hook =
    \SetQuestionPropertiesX{ section-title = \unexpanded\expandafter{\secName} }
}

\newcommand{\secName}{}
\newcommand{\lsection}[1]{\renewcommand*{\secName}{#1}\section{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lsection{One}

\begin{question}
  say foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  foo
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  say bar
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  bar
\end{solution}

\lsection{Two}

\begin{question}
  say baz
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  baz
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  say foobar
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  foobar
\end{solution}

\lsection{Answers}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I accepted this answer as it has the clues to solve the expansion issue without "digging" into `exsheets` internals. But I'll use one of the 2 codes provided in the two answers. Thank you!   As for the `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, does it clash with something in `exsheets`? If not, this is meant for the entire book - not even one word is outside the `question` or `solution` environments and everything is very cramped. Sort of a "save the trees" typesetting for a colection of exercises "book". But I suppose I can use the koma-script classes (using plain old {report} now) if needed.

Comment: The parindent thing is a typographical one: if you set `\parindent` to zero readers might not have any clue when a paragraph ends and a new one starts. So the usual practice is to at least introduce a vertical skip between paragraphs then. Doing this manually (`\setlength{\parskip}{\baselineskip}`) can lead to unexpected results, though. KOMA-Script's option handles this correctly.

Comment: For other classes there is the [`parskip`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/parskip) package. (I assumed you're already using KOMA-Script since your example uses `scrartcl` instead of `article`...)

Comment: For now I have to mimic the typesetting of an existing book (printed every year for the past 20 years) and there's no indentation whatsoever except chapters/section titles. New paragraph means new exercise. The exercise number typesetting (bold, bigger, whatever) provides the clue as where a new block of text starts. There are no paragraphs within an exercise except lists made with `tasks` or `shortlst`. But I will try using packages instead. Thanks

Comment: @alwaysask In almost all books I have ever seen there is either a paragraph indent *or* a paragraph skip. Your example had neither...

Comment: @cg Me too. Except this one which (1) was typeset by someone who didn't have a clue about typesetting and (2) the editor will have the typesetter shot if he needs to add more than 2 pages (~ 150 p per book) due to "wasted page real estate". There are > 10 books in the collection (printed every summer) and until all of them will be in TeX (2-3 years) the newly typeset (TeX) ones will have to look identical with the ones using the old typeset (ancient Adobe PM). When all the books will be typeset in TeX, we will shoot the editor and tweak back the par settings etc from then on :)

Answer (score 3):

This is an “illegal” answer, as the code I propose relies on defining a variant of an internal command. The answer is so mainly aimed to give ideas to the package developer.

I define a command `\DeclareQuestionPropertyFixed` that takes as arguments a property name and the variable from which the value should be obtained from, in this case

```
\DeclareQuestionPropertyFixed{section-title}{\secName}
```

so one has just to do

```
\SetupExSheets{
  ...
  question/pre-body-hook = \SetQuestionProperties{section-title},
}
```

Complete code.

```
\documentclass[parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{exsheets}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \DeclareQuestionPropertyFixed { m m }
 {
  \exsheets_declare_question_property:n {#1--fixed}
  \keys_define:nn { question / meta }
   {
    #1 .code:n = \__exsheets_question_set_property:nV { #1--fixed } #2
   }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__exsheets_question_set_property:nn {nV}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareQuestionPropertyFixed{section-title}{\secName}
\SetupExSheets{
  counter-within = section ,
  headings = inline-nr ,
  counter-format = qu). ,
  section-hook = \noindent\bfseries Section 
                 \GetQuestionProperty{section-title}{\CurrentQuestionID}\space ,
  question/pre-body-hook = \SetQuestionProperties{section-title}
}

\newcommand{\secName}{}
\newcommand{\lsection}[1]{\renewcommand*{\secName}{#1}\section{#1}}

\begin{document}

\lsection{One}

\begin{question}
  say foo
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  foo
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  say bar
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  bar
\end{solution}

\lsection{Two}

\begin{question}
  say baz
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  baz
\end{solution}

\begin{question}
  say foobar
\end{question}
\begin{solution}
  foobar
\end{solution}

\lsection{Answers}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: interesting idea!